# How do i set the iPod volume without affecting other sound levels?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, volume, mpmusicplayercontroller

I tried setting the iPod volume level before, but it affected the volume of my app, which uses MPMusicPlayer. Any solution to this?

Comment: I think this is by design. Apple wants things like volume to be system wide so that users don't get their ears blown off/think their iPod is broken when they swap apps etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is playing music locally (not affecting the iPod app) you can use *MPMusicPlayerController* to create an *application music player* and then set the volume property to whatever you want.

[MPMusicPlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221)